Movie with comedy sketches from late '70's/early 80's
With the release of Movie 43 earlier this year, it reminded me of a comedy that I saw when I was younger.  
I am guessing it was released in the late 1970's or early 1980's and was filled with nothing but different comedy sketches very similar to Movie 43. I am pretty sure many of them were probably inappropriate for a child to be watching due to nudity. 
I remember that some of the skits were parodies of the news, tv shows and movies.  The one I can recall the most was a sketch that included a dead body being brought to family functions similar to Weekend at Bernies.  
Can anyone recognize this?

One such movie was The Groove Tube (1974), though I don't remember the particular sketch that you mentioned.
Another was Kentucky Fried Movie (1977) which I have not seen.

It was Kentucky Fried Movie!!!  I remember the shoe on the cover now. Thanks, it was driving me crazy!
